# How to add a decommissioned node to the same cluster without data loss?

Tags: cassandra

I just did nodetool decommission and it removed the node from the cluster and I am trying to add it back to the same cluster but its not joining. I searched the internet and a lot of people are saying to delete the data folder, log folder and cache's from the node but I need the data. Please someone help me.

Comment: Check the `system.log` for an error about why it isn't joining.  My guess, is that you'll have to specify a replacement address in `cassandra-env-sh`.

Comment: When you delete the node then data will not be lost as long as your replication factor of your data is > 1 (which means another copy exists). Deleting the data, log and cache folder will make the node look like new node and join the cluster. Which will get synced once joined into the cluster.

Comment: ERROR LOG:This node was decommissioned and will not rejoin the ring unless cassandra.override_decommission=true has been set, or all existing data is removed and the node is bootstrapped again
Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
ERROR [main] 2017-08-30 09:03:16,928 CassandraDaemon.java:752 - Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: this node was decommissioned and will not rejoin the ring unless cassandra.override_decommission=true has been set, or all existing data is removed and the node is bootstrapped again

Comment: I am new cassandra, I don't how to specify a replacement address in cassandra-env.sh and searching for high availability cassandra cluster @Aaron@Shoban Sunday